# How to set static readonly fields dynamically?

Tags: c#, dynamic, static, readonly

I have run into a "problem" when designing a node class for a 2D BSP tree. Below is a list of the things I want accomplished.

1. I want all the nodes to have the same value for some of their fields.
2. I want these fields to be readonly, since it would be bad / not make sense for the value of any field to be changed once the first node in the tree has been created.
3. I want to be able to set these values before building the tree.

The solution to point 1 is to make the fields static. Making the fields `static readonly` (points 1 + 2) means that the values have to be set either directly or in the static constructor. Setting the values in the static constructor using some configuration file / class / whatever is an option. Is is the "correct" / only way?

**Edited to remove text about multiple trees with different node values since it makes the whole point of having static fields useless.**

Comment: How about a class for the tree and another for the nodes within a tree? The nodes can be constructed with a reference back to the tree and, therefore, their common values for that specific tree.

Comment: @HABO Yes. Already have a tree class. The solution is so simple. For some reason my brain was locked in to the thought of keeping the values in the node class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marking the fields as static is not the best option in your scenario as you clearly state that not all nodes share the same value for this particular field (instead, the value depends on the tree they are associated with).

Do the nodes have a reference to the tree itself? Then you can provide a property similar to:

```
public int MyProperty
{
   get
   {
       return this._tree.CommonValue;
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 for correctly pointing out that `static` unifies it at a level too high.

Comment: The nodes do not currently have a reference to the tree. It certainly is an option.  I also just now realized that by adding talk about multiple trees to the question after the initial draft it makes the static fields kind of useless, as you pointed out. Will edit the question to remove that part.